# CSS to apply if 2 elements exist

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given the following HTML markup, I want to apply (S)CSS only when **2** of the same elements exist (not when 1 exists).

I don't want to use JavaScript to count the number of elements and apply another class, however, I feel this is the only approach.

```
div {
  a + a {
    // I want to apply styles to both a tags, not just the second one
    // WHEN 2 a tags exists
  } 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
</a>
```

Comment: https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "quantity queries". For **exactly** TWO...

```
a:nth-last-child(n+2):nth-last-child(-n+2):first-child, 
a:nth-last-child(n+2):nth-last-child(-n+2):first-child ~ a {

}
```

Source: https://quantityqueries.com/

```css
a:nth-last-child(n+2):nth-last-child(-n+2):first-child,
a:nth-last-child(n+2):nth-last-child(-n+2):first-child~a {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a>

</div>

<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
  <a href="/more">More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

<sup>**UPDATE**: the initial question stated "**2 or more** of the same elements exist" but was updated later ...</sup>

You can do it like below:

```css
a:first-child:nth-last-child(n + 2),
a ~ *{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a> <a href="/about">About</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a> <a href="/about">About</a> <a href="/">Home</a> <a href="/about">About</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
</div>
```

Or like below too:

```css
a:not(:only-child){
  color:red; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a> <a href="/about">About</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a> <a href="/about">About</a> <a href="/">Home</a> <a href="/about">About</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies, I did state 2 or more originally, then changed the requirement.

Comment: Just to clarify, 2 or more elements is perfectly acceptable and a valid answer.

Answer (score -3):

are you using pre-compilor? 
then

```css
div a:nth-child(n+2) {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
</a>
```

For Scss, following code should work

```
div {
   & a:nth-child(n+2) {
    // css instruction
  } 
}
```

Comment: Your answer is false. Please take the time needed to test your answer before posting it.