# CSS to check element exists and apply to first element

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML, I want to be able to apply CSS to the `.first` element where `.second` exists. I understand `:has` isn't available at the moment, and ideally I **don't** want to use JavaScript.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS for `:has` I'd assume would be below. Is there any other CSS I can apply to make this work without the usage of `:has`.

```css
.container > .first:has(+ .second) {
  // styles here
}
```

If `.second` doesn't exist, then no CSS style should apply.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62469590/8620333

Answer (score 0):

In your simple example you could work with `:not()`, like

```
.container > .first:not(:only-child) {
     // styles
}
```

For more complex scenarios you may need a little more creativity, but hope this gives you an idea.